# To Convert StringBuffer To A Byte Array In Java

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuffer

I have a StringBuffer,`strbuf=161656070200000000202020202001000000009E52;`.

I want to convert into a byte array that looks like this:

```
byte[] byte_array=new byte[]
 {(byte)0x16,(byte)0x16,(byte)0x56,(byte)0x07,
  (byte)0x02,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,
  (byte)0x00,(byte)0x20,(byte)0x20,(byte)0x20,
  (byte)0x20,(byte)0x20,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,
  (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x9E,(byte)0x52};
```

Do I need to convert `strbuf` to `hex` string and then do  `getBytes()`?
What is the right approach to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
final String longHex = "161656070200000000202020202001000000009E52";
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(longHex, 16).toByteArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

prints

```
[22, 22, 86, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -98, 82]
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's break the problem down, and work backwards here.

Do you know:

- How to convert an `int` into a `byte` (assuming the former is in range)?
- How to convert a two-character `String` into an `int`?
- How to convert a long String into chunks of two characters each?

I suspect that you are able to do any of these tasks individually.  Simply doing all of them in sequence (in reverse order) will yield the solution you're looking for.

`</teaching-to-fish>`

Comment: instead of asking me what i know, i think it would be better if you explain us in your "systematic" way..

Comment: Perhaps.  But merely giving you a chunk of code will let you copy-paste, move on, and then come back to SO next time you get stuck.  Instead, leading you through the steps required to realise the solution on your own is more time-consuming, but means you can resolve similar problems yourself in future - which *makes you a better developer*.

Comment: i dont know what to say. Since i couldnt find a solution, i posted this question. And thank u very much..

Answer (score 0):

```
String longHex = "....";
byte[] array = new byte[longHex.length() / 2];
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
     Byte byte = Byte.parseByte(longHex.substring(i*2, i*2+2), 16);
     array[i] = byte;
}
```